# How do I index a dataframe using a list of datetime indices in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

If I want to locate one datetime index, I would use:

```
df.loc['2018-11-27 12:30:00']
```

But I have a list of datetime indexes

```
DatetimeIndex(['2018-11-27 12:30:00', '2018-12-07 18:00:00',
               '2018-12-15 16:30:00', '2019-01-13 20:30:00',
               '2019-01-28 16:00:00', '2019-02-06 15:30:00',
               '2019-03-04 11:00:00', '2019-03-14 15:00:00',
               '2019-03-25 21:00:00', '2019-04-15 20:30:00',
               ...
               '2021-04-14 07:00:00', '2021-05-08 20:30:00',
               '2021-06-03 10:30:00', '2021-06-15 18:30:00',
               '2021-06-29 17:30:00', '2021-08-23 12:00:00',
               '2021-09-07 03:00:00', '2021-09-18 06:00:00',
               '2021-10-20 16:00:00', '2021-11-10 18:00:00'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='time', length=232, freq=None)
```

How do I pass them all into the dataframe?

I get this error if I use df.loc[indexes]:

```
KeyError: "None of [DatetimeIndex(['2018-11-27 12:30:00', '2018-12-07 18:00:00',\n               '2018-12-15 16:30:00', '2019-01-13 20:30:00',\n               '2019-01-28 16:00:00', '2019-02-06 15:30:00',\n               '2019-03-04 11:00:00', '2019-03-14 15:00:00',\n               '2019-03-25 21:00:00', '2019-04-15 20:30:00',\n               ...\n               '2021-04-14 07:00:00', '2021-05-08 20:30:00',\n               '2021-06-03 10:30:00', '2021-06-15 18:30:00',\n               '2021-06-29 17:30:00', '2021-08-23 12:00:00',\n               '2021-09-07 03:00:00', '2021-09-18 06:00:00',\n               '2021-10-20 16:00:00', '2021-11-10 18:00:00'],\n              dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='time', length=232, freq=None)] are in the [index]"
```

Answer (score 0):

Test `df.index` with list:

```
 df[df.index.isin(L)]
```

Comment: It's not working. I get all false values and an empty dataframe. It shouldn't happen because if I write the dates individually, I can locate them in df

Comment: @Astrofolia - Is there `DatetimeIndex` ?

Comment: Oh you're right :D. For some reason, my dataframe indexes weren't a DatetimeIndex type, so when I fixed it, it was able to process the list correctly.